# how I can find the generator of primitive group in Sage

Tags: sage

I am not familiar with sage,(I dont know anythink about it) but I have very basic question. I need the generators of primitive group(15,2) for my reaserch., could anyone give me the generators of primitive group(15,2) ,with using Sage? I would be appreciate

Answer (score 2):

You must be referring to [The primitive group from the GAP tables of primitive groups](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_named.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_named.PrimitiveGroup).  Interestingly, it's not clear to me whether these are in exact correspondence with "primitive permutation groups", though I assume they are.

Anyway, since you are using that notation, I assume that [this will do it for you](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwLULBVCCjKzM0sySxLdS_KLy3QMDTVMdLk5QrQS0_NK9bQBAC8jgo8&lang=sage):

```
sage: P = PrimitiveGroup(15,2)
sage: P.gens()
[(1,4,5)(2,8,10)(3,12,15)(6,13,11)(7,9,14), (1,15,7,5,12)(2,9,13,14,8)(3,6,10,11,4)]
```

Note that although `P` apparently is isomorphic to the alternating group on six elements, nonetheless it appears (as you probably wish) as a permutation group on 15 elements.

Comment: Also note that this *requires* the optional `database_gap` package in SageMath (this package may become standard soon, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-devel/-rONOVlS6gs)).